# Stiff trackpad on Macbook air

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

I just got a used Early 2015 Macbook Air. I got it a bit cheap, due to the trackpad being stiff.

Basically when I first open it, it registers all clicks, although I need to press somewhat hard. But if I click on it about 50 times, it starts to loosen up a bit, and act more like a normal trackpad would. However, if I then leave it for an hour, it is back to being stiff again.

**What could the problem be, and is it fixable?**

The rest of the computer works perfectly fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trackpad is most likely bad.  It's not unheard of, after all, it is a *mechanical* device to some extent.

It could be either it's just worn out or there may have been some sort of liquid spill like juice that is causing it to become "sticky" (I personally repaired this condition).

There is the possibility that the battery may be swollen (you may have to examine it when the back cover is off; even remove the battery).  If that's the case, you will also want to replace the battery.  I recommend getting one with at least an [18 month warranty](http://radnex.us/MBA-2010-2014-battery).

You can get a replacement [trackpad](http://radnex.us/MBA-13inch-2013-2015-trackpad) fairly inexpensively, but it will take some effort - you will have to remove the battery.  [Ifixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Early+2015+Trackpad+Replacement/38544) has an excellent step-by-step guide to walk you through.

As you can see in the pictures, once you have the back cover off, you can gain access to the battery.  After you remove the battery, you then have access to the trackpad.

[image]
[image]

This is not a *difficult* repair, but detail oriented.  If you take your time, you should be able to accomplish this.  If not, any reputable repair shop can tackle this for you.

Comment: Thank you Allan for your reply. I fear that the battery might be swollen, as the trackpad doesn't exactly feel sticky in any way.  I'm gonna get some tools from ifixit, and see if i can sort it diagnose it. :)

Answer (score 1):

My advice if you can still move the cursor is to enable tap to click under settings.

[image]

Comment: Did that already, but i like the tactile feedback tho. :) Thx for your reply tho.